# How would I create a LEFT JOIN SQL query in Access using the Query Wizard?

Tags: sql, query

Is this even possible? I always end up with INNER JOIN after viewing the SQL that the wizard provides. I know how to write the query myself. I'm just trying to figure out if I should be selecting different options in the Query Wizard to make it do it automatically. Below, you'll find a description of what I'm expecting and my table designs:

The query should return all rows from TABLE_USERS. If a row in TABLE_USERS has data in the GroupName field, the query should return the GroupDescription from TABLE_GROUPS.

**TABLE_USERS**

Username

GroupName

**TABLE_GROUPS**

GroupName

GroupDescription

Answer (score 1):

[MS shows how to create SQL for inner and outer joins](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6), both by writing code and also using the designer. Specifically, to use the query Design view to create an *outer* join:

- Double-click an existing *inner* join.
- In the Join Properties dialog box, select from the choices listed by option 2 and option 3.

That said, my preference is to write the SQL myself, as it's faster and less prone to error.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Worked like a charm!